Stripe not processing debit card payments
Stripe not completing debit card payments.  Stripe reports that debit cards are handled along with credit cards.

Hi Dave! It may be worth adding a little more detail including CiviCRM version, Stripe version and any errors you are getting in either Civi or Stripe as it may be specific to your setup / version (our set up does have recurring contributions in progress with debit cards for example).

Good point - although my primary question would be is anyone else experiencing this type of issue.    The versions are Civi 5.69 and Stripe extension 6.10.2.    Stripe says that debit cards are managed with the same process as credit cards so should not be an issue

Do you get any errors? We have no issues with debit cards used on any site so any detail on what isn't working would be good to see

According to the client, the 'errors" are the creation of a large number of duplicate entries that are not valid.

As in a 'pending' as well as a completed one for recurring payments? If so, worth looking  at this known issue https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/442

that issue is for recurring payments.  Our issue is only with debit cards

It would be really good to get full details of the error, i.e. the actual Stripe or Civi detail with further info on the duplicate
